# What a demonstration proposal is?

Tags: paper-submission

I was looking at a conference's deadlines and one of them refers to the "Submission of demonstration proposals". I couldn't figure out what a demonstration proposal actually is.

Comment: What field is this?

Comment: @Buffy Computer Science!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demonstration is a showcase for a tool developed as part of a research activity. A demonstration proposal is a short paper outlining what capabilities of your tool are you going to show and why they're significant.

Normally a demonstration does not present breaking research, rather it demonstrates practical implementation of existing - but still relatively new - research.   I speak for CS.  Your mileage may vary on other fields.